# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when creating a table in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-00907

In Oracle 11G, am recieving the error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` when creating the table shown below

```
create table structured_1000( 
year varchar2(4) NOT NULL,
    CP varchar2(50),
      ONSG varchar2(50),
      ONSLA varchar2(9),
      road varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
      cat varchar2(20)
  Refs varchar2(20),
  Refn varchar2(20),
  ajunction varchar2(20),
  bjunction varchar2 (20),
  lennet char(2)`
   );
```

Ive listed the entire table as sometimes the error line changes - has shown both line 6 & 9. From what I can see all of the parenthesis are visible. This issue occurs in both the shell and APEX.

Comment: Are you sure you have `lennet char(2)`` (extra backticks)?

Comment: @SMA, as someone fairly new to Oracle, what do you mean by backtick?

Comment: @SMA not that I am aware of - the table isnt being created, just the error

Comment: create table structured_1000( 
year varchar2(4) NOT NULL,
    CP varchar2(50),
      ONSG varchar2(50),
      ONSLA varchar2(9),
      road varchar2(100) NOT NULL,
      cat varchar2(20)
  Refs varchar2(20),
  Refn varchar2(20),
  ajunction varchar2(20),
  bjunction varchar2 (20),
  lennet char(2)
   );

Comment: `cat varchar2(20) Refs varchar2(20)` what do you mean by this?

Comment: cat and Refs are attribute names; im hoping to import a csv file that has these headings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your **create table statement**:

1. 

> cat varchar2(20)
>   
>   You have a **missing comma**.

2. 

> lennet char(2)`
>   
>   An **invalid backtick** in the end.

Fixing the two issue would successfully create the table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE structured_1000
  2    (
  3      YEAR      VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  4      CP        VARCHAR2(50),
  5      ONSG      VARCHAR2(50),
  6      ONSLA     VARCHAR2(9),
  7      road      VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
  8      cat       VARCHAR2(20),
  9      Refs      VARCHAR2(20),
 10      Refn      VARCHAR2(20),
 11      ajunction VARCHAR2(20),
 12      bjunction VARCHAR2 (20),
 13      lennet    CHAR(2)
 14    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your create table. You are missing comma between two field definition like:

```
cat varchar2(20)
Refs varchar2(20),
```

So use "," (comma) to seperate two fields like

```
 cat varchar2(20),
                 ^
Refs varchar2(20),
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out 

Now im getting `ora-00904 invalid identifier`

Comment: Year is a reserved word so rename it. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) for reserved words.